# grep exact match of string with alphabets and numbers

Tags: grep, exact-match

I am using grep to extract lines from file 1 that matches with string in file2. The string in file 2 has both alphabets and numbers. eg;

```
MSTRG.18691.1
MSTRG.18801.1
```

I used `sed` to write word boundaries for all the strings in the file 2.

```
file 2
\<MSTRG.18691.1\>
\<MSTRG.18801.1\>
```

and used `grep -f file2 file1`

but output has

```
MSTRG.18691.1.2
MSTRG.18801.1.3 also..
```

I want lines that matches exactly,

```
MSTRG.18691.1
MSTRG.18801.1
```

and not,

```
MSTRG.18691.1.2
MSTRG.18801.1.3
```

Few lines from my file1
`t_name  gene_name       FPKM    TPM

MSTRG.25.1      .       0       0

rna71519        .       93.398872       194.727926057583

gene34024       ND1     2971.72876      6195.77694943117

MSTRG.28.1      .       0       0

MSTRG.28.2      .       0       0

rna71520        .       33.235409       69.2927240732149`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Updating the answer**

You can use `start with ^` and `end with $` operator to match start with and begin with. To match exactly **MSTRG.18691.1** you can add **^** & **$** at  both ends and remove the word boundaries, additionally `.` has special meaning in regex to match exactly `.` we need to escape that with a backslash `\`

*Example pattern:*

```
^MSTRG\.18691\.1$
^MSTRG\.18801\.1$
```

**file1**

```
MSTRG.18691.1
MSTRG.1311.1
MSTRG.18801.2
MSTRG.18801.3
MSTRG.18801.1.2
MSTRG.18801.1.1
MSTRG.18801.1
PrefixMSTRG.18801.1
```

Just create a normal file named file1 and paste the above content into it.

**file2** (pattern file)

```
^MSTRG\.18801\.1$
```

Just create a normal file named file2 and paste the above content into it.

Run the below command from commandline

```
grep -i --color -f file2 file1
```

**Result:**

```
MSTRG.18801.1
```

**Sed to add changes to the pattern file**

Here is the `sed command` to escape `.` and add `^` and `$` at the beginning and end of the pattern file you already have.

```
sed -Ee 's/\./\\./g' -e 's/^/\^/g' -e 's/$/\$/g' file2 > file2_updated
```

> -E to support extended regex on BSD sed, you may need to replace -E with -r based on your system's sed

Updated patterns will be saved to file2_updated. Need to use the new pattern file in grep like this

```
grep -i -f file2_updated file1
```

Comment: Also there are strings like `MSTRG.13.1` in file 2 but grep returns `MSTRG.1311.1` which is not in file2.

Comment: Please, check the updated answer. A dot (.) has special meaning to regex, we need to escape that to not match any single character.

Comment: I used `sed 's/^/^/' file 2 | sed 's/$/$/' | sed 's/./\\./'` to make this `^MSTRG\.18691\.1$` pattern. But the whole file is repalced with `\.`. How to add back slash before the dot?

Comment: why you need sed? you can use plain grep to match words or line. Still, if you need to use sed to do some intermediate stream conversion, you can do that then you can grep to match patterns. You only need backslash in pattern file.

Comment: I am at a very beginner level in linux. I don't know how to create the pattern file `^MSTRG\.18801\.1$` to use with `grep -f`. I know to use `sed` to add `^` at start and `$` at end of the line. I dont know how to add back slash before dot in pattern file (i.e. file2)

Comment: I created file2 with pattern   `^MSTRG\.18801\.1$` it works, with and without `-i --color`. Thank you. But my original `file2` has around 5500 lines. How can I edit that file such that it has `^` as the start; `$` as the end and backslash before dot `.` ?

Comment: Great that you have made it this far. :) I will post the sed command to replace those, for the time being, you can use sublime or some other text editor to find and replace those. I used -i to ignore case and --color to show matching color.

Comment: `sed` worked perfectly, thank you. But `grep` outputs nothing. The `updated_file2` works well on the custom created file1, but not on my original file1. My original file1 is a tab-delimited file with 3 columns and I am applying `grep` to the first column.

Comment: Can you please add part of the actual file1?

Comment: t_name gene_name FPKM TPM                                                                                                           
gene34025       ND2     3560.135498     7422.5500                                                
MSTRG.22.3      .       831.061035      1732.6846                
MSTRG.22.4      .       0       0                 
MSTRG.28.3      .       435.921539      908.8557                                                                                                          This is a file with 4 columns. Many entries in the `2nd column` are a `dot (.)`

Comment: Can you please add this in you question as sample to keep formatting?

Comment: I replaced `.` in the 2nd column as `UNKNOWN`. Modified the pattern file as `MSTRG\.18801\.1` (removed `^` at start and `$` at end ). Now it works fine. Is the correct way? Thankyou. I have updated the qstn with file1

Comment: That's correct if you want to match any string from any part of a line that matches `MSTRG\.18801\.1`. If a line is like this `MSTRG.18801.1.1   hello world!`, that pattern will match `MSTRG.18801.1` and show the whole line as output.  You can accept my answer if it was helpful. Thanks :)

Comment: But I need exact match of **`MSTRG.18801.1` only, not `MSTRG.18801.1.1`**. Will editing the pattern to `\<MSTRG\.18801\.1\>` give only `MSTRG.18801.1` as output?

Comment: What you can do is use `ggrep` that supports print only matching.  Here is the ggrep command for that `ggrep -o  -f file2_updated file1`

Answer (score 0):

The flag you're looking for is `-F`. From `man grep`:

> -F, --fixed-strings
>
> Interpret PATTERN as a list of fixed strings (instead of regular expressions), separated by newlines, any of which is to be matched.

You can use this quite comfortably in conjunction with `-f`:

```
grep -Ff file2 file1
```

To be clear, this will treat every line of `file2` as an exact match against `file1`.

Comment: @KousalyaDevi What?

Comment: I used `grep -Ff file2 file1` It works for `MSTRG.13.1` (there is no MSTRG.1311.1 in output), but `file2` has `MSTRG.11443.1` but output has `MSTRG.11443.10` and `MSTRG.11443.13`. I used this with file without word boundaries

Comment: @KousalyaDevi It won't work if you still have word boundaries added to file2

Comment: `file1` is a tab delimited file with 3 columns. In which, some entries in second column are `.`  I am using `grep` on first column.